# How the Pull request process works in Continuous integration using Travis CI and github?

Tags: git, github, travis-ci, pull-request

My Requirement is: Developer x forked the branch from one of the **public repository** and perform changes in his local drive and made a pull request against the master. The Owner/admin of the master repository sees the **pull request** in the master repository. What is the **role of Travis CI** after admin sees the pull request on master repository?

I am planning to do the automation process of build and perform unit tests for these pull requests.. Some one please give me the steps to achieve this.

BTW: I am using **Public repository**.

Thanks,

Comment: Forked or cloned? And read the travis docs for more details. It is pretty straightforward

Comment: @TheGeorgeous - It's a forked and cloned into the local repo. I have an automation script working for every commit but in case, a pull request triggers how it works? I saw the documentation about TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST but not clear where to write this? Could you please explain me the process..

Comment: I would suggest reading the docs from beginning rather than just one article. You will get a little more context on how to do it

Comment: I refereed so many documents but didn't find a solution for this. Some one please give me a solution. Is this possible? How Travis CI knows when a pull request comes to the Master Repository?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, Travis CI has an out of the box feature to build pull requests. What it does is build a merged version of the PR and show a status to it, so the person in charge of check/approve the PR could take the PR build status into account.

More info [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests/)